# PushWoosh doesnt work on my Cordova app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I have implemented this string [Pushwoosh_LOG_LEVEL = DEBUG] on info for a check on debug monitor to find the problems in it...but this is result...

> *2017-02-23 17:02:28.238165 The Emerald[4948:2354975] [PW] [D] __34-[PWDataManagerCommon] sending appOpen completed 2017-02-23 17:02:28.711378 The Emerald[4948:2354975] [PW] [I]
>   -[PWPushNotificationsManagerCommon] Registered for push notifications: dca8926d33cdcade565493543d652cfe30ece1562f80a67939c875f275e5dce7
>   2017-02-23 17:02:29.357496 The Emerald[4948:2354975] [PW] [I]
>   -[PWRequestManager]  x |    Pushwoosh request: | Url:      https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/setTags | Payload: 
>   {"request":{"device_type":1,"tags":{"uuid":"B3445D4C-9ED1-4A28-B649-81246B803BC4"},"application":"38291-F3F53","userId":"B3445D4C-9ED1-4A28-B649-81246B803BC4","v":"4.2.0","hwid":"B3445D4C-9ED1-4A28-B649-81246B803BC4"}}
>   | Status:   "200 no error" | Response:
>   {"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":{"skipped":[]}} x
>   2017-02-23 17:02:29.357614 The Emerald[4948:2354975] [PW] [D]
>   __46-[PWDataManagerCommon] setTags completed

I think push doesnt work...

Under the Framework dir i see **lib.dylib** and **libstdc++.dylib** in red [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcIg5.png)

I follow this guide docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/native-ios-sdk but in the point 2

i can't find libz and libstdc++

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

-[PWPushNotificationsManagerCommon] Registered for push notifications: dca8926d33cdcade565493543d652cfe30ece1562f80a67939c875f275e5dce7

This means you have registered for push notifications. Have you tried sending push when your phone is on 3G network? Sometimes wi-fi router blocks push notifications.

Comment: Hi, i have try with 3G but don't work...

I have find this warning on the history tab in PushWoosh panel 

(Device Push Token is invalid or cannot be found in the database. Please check that your build matches your gateway (Sandbox/Production)

This is possible solution but i have try to delete all push cert in my keychain and re download but push not work !

[I re-downloaded the push production certificate and exported it from the keychain as .p12. This seems to have solved the problem. It seems strange though that a bad private key was giving me the "Invalid Token" error.]